# New WebView in Android KitKat problems

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat, hwui

My app is using a `WebView` to display a long text

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView mWebView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(mWebView);

    String s = getHtml(); //get a long html from a file

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", s, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

the app works well on older versions of Android,
but when running on KitKat, this error appears in the logcat when the WebView is created or destroyed:

```
libGLESv2(21582): HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context F:ES3-glDeleteShader
```

I have read "Migrating to WebView in Android 4.4" but I cannot solve the problem.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Having the same problem on 4.4.4. Anyone having an idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
```

Comment: @konkot what do you mean by did not work?Please clear project and retry.And also post logcat info if it is different.

Comment: that error is still appear in logcat: libGLESv2(21582): HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context F:ES3-glDeleteShader

Answer (score 2):

add

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```